# javascript code is not executing if i open the link in new tab

Tags: javascript

html code:

```
<div class="dummy">
    <a href ="www.test.com" title="EA">test</a>
</div>
```

javascript Code:

```
$('.dummy').on('click',function(e){
    alert('good moring'); 
});
```

The above javascript code is not executing if i open the link in new tab,can someone help me out..

Comment: do you have jQuery included, any console errors?

Comment: javascript or  jquery??

Comment: @mxr7350-the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) getting this console error

Comment: @Alessandro Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a `a` element inside your `DIV`. SO in order to have your `alert` just prevent the default action of anchor element using

```
e.preventDefault();
```

[Read more on event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
$('.dummy').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('good moring');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dummy">
  <a href="www.test.com" title="EA">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ya i understand..but the test link which u sent cant able to open in new tab.getting 404 error